# Raise ValueError with message, but don't print message

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a FileNotFound error, which I would like to handle by raising a ValueError. The ValueError should come with a message, but this message shouldn't be displayed.

```
def check_file(file):
    try: 
        #open file here
    except FileNotFoundError: 
        raise ValueError("Caught a FileNotFoundError")
    except ValueError:
        print("This is the only thing I want shown)
```

Current output:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nonexistent_file.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError: Caught a FileNotFoundError.
```

Desired output:

```
This is the only thing I want shown
```

Comment: Use a `try: ... try: ...` block.

Comment: @stovfl how do you mean?

Comment: move the statement `raise valueError` inside of another `try except` block.

Comment: Why do you want to mask the `FileNotFoundError`? it's usually a bad practice. If you are already catching `ValueError` in the calling code, then catch both (`except (ValueError, FileNotFoundError)`)

Comment: @DeepSpace Surely it's a very common thing to do: e.g. when trying to open an optional config file which hasn't been created yet. Using a try/except like that avoids a race condition. It would certainly be bad practice to catch ValueError in the way you suggest, though, since that very likely *would* mask errors.

Comment: @novice Please explain more clearly what actual problem you are trying to solve with this code.

Comment: @ekhumoro Race condition between what? How does `except FileNotFoundError` introduce a race condition that `except ValueError` would not?

Comment: @DeepSpace It doesn't introduce one - it avoids one. A race condition might occur if you did something like `if os.path.exists(file)` instead. Using a try/except with FileNotFoundError avoids that possibility (a simple case of EAFP). The issue with the ValueError is entirely separate. It's a bad idea because it could mask real errors instead of just the one the OP is explicitly trying to raise.

Comment: @ekhumoro I've never said OP should use `os.path.exists`. I just did not understand why OP tries to raise a `ValueError` from a `FileNotFoundError` instead of simply catching  `FileNotFoundError`

Comment: @DeepSpace Sure - but you said it was "usually a bad practice", and I just gave a simple, common example that proves it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand why you want to raise a ValueError. If you just want "This is the only thing I want shown" to show you can just do this

```
def check_file(file):
    try: 
        #open file here
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("This is the only thing I want shown)
```

If you need to raise a ValueError please tell me why and ill try to figure it out but i dont believe its nessesary

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the call to the `check_file` function in `try: ... except:` as follows:

```
def check_file(file):
    try: 
        #open file here
    except FileNotFoundError: 
        raise ValueError("Caught a FileNotFoundError")

try:
    check_file("test")
except ValueError:
    print("This is the only thing I want shown")
```